# Change RadioButton image in fragment from the activity

Tags: android, radio-button

I want to change the radio button images in the fragment when a button in the activity is clicked, so I am trying to call a method in my fragment that change the images but it is not working, this is my code:

My Fragment:

```
public class ChoicesFragment extends Fragment {
    RadioButton rd1;
    RadioButton rd2;
    RadioButton rd3;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choices, container, false);
        rd1=(RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        rd2=(RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        rd3=(RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.choice3);
        return view;
    }
    public void setRadioButtonsImages(int choix1, int choix2, int choix3){
        rd1.setButtonDrawable(choix1);
        rd2.setButtonDrawable(choix2);
        rd3.setButtonDrawable(choix3);
    }
}
```

And in my activity:

```
public void showImages(View view) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction  = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    cf = new ChoicesFragment();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container2, cf,"choicesFragment").addToBackStack(null).commit();
    Resources res = getResources();
    int choix1 = res.getIdentifier(level.getChoix1(),"drawable",getPackageName());
    int choix2 = res.getIdentifier(level.getChoix2(),"drawable",getPackageName());
    int choix3 = res.getIdentifier(level.getChoix3(),"drawable",getPackageName());
    cf.setRadioButtonImage(choix1,choix2,choix3);
}
```

And I get this error

```
04-25 12:39:28.734 29413-29413/com.example.mireille.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
         Process: com.example.mireille.test, PID: 29413
         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioButton.setButtonDrawable(int)' on a null object reference
             at com.example.mireille.simplegame.ChoicesFragment.setRadioButtonImage(ChoicesFragment.java:37)
             at com.example.mireille.simplegame.MainActivity.changeLevel(MainActivity.java:60)
             at com.example.mireille.simplegame.MainActivity.startRotatingImage(MainActivity.java:48)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Thanks

Comment: you are calling this method `cf.setRadioButtonImage(choix1,choix2,choix3);` from actvity this will cause a exception... you can put this method on OnResume method of fragment

Comment: Okay thanks I will try it

Comment: Did it work to call setRadioButtonImage() method from fragment?

Comment: Yes, it did work.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh can you explain me why onResume?

Comment: yes @Mireille you are replacing the fragment same time calling that method.. fragment take some time to create view .. so all UI update need to done when OnCreateView method called otherwise it will throw `NullPointerException` because UI element object  is not initialised yet.. onResume will called after onCreateView and onViewCreated